# No route matches, rails using wrong controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I'm coming back to a rails project that I haven't looked at in a while. This is probably something very simple that I can't see.

I have a mostly static view on my app for an FAQ. When I rake routes it shows up fine:

```
faq        /faq(.:format)     base_pages#faq
```

I set up a very simple rspec test to make sure it's working:

```
describe "BasePages" do
    describe "FAQ" do
        before { visit faq_path }

        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "FAQ") }
    end
end
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
  1) BasePages FAQ 
     Failure/Error: before { visit faq_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"festivals", :id=>nil}
     # ./app/views/base_pages/faq.html.erb:130:in `_app_views_base_pages_faq_html_erb___446447898979674530_70112514729120'
     # ./spec/requests/base_pages_spec.rb:105:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Below is my config/routes.rb:

```
Cif::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts

  match '/news', to: 'posts#index'

  get "payment/cancel"

  get "payment/success"

  post "payment/record"

  post "stripe_events/record"

  resources :submissions do
    resources :links, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :performers, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :festivals, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :submissions, only: :index
  resources :admin, only: :index
  resources :curator, only: :index

  devise_for :users

  namespace :admin do
    resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
    resources :submissions do
      member do
        get 'notify'
        get 'format_for_wordpress'
      end
    end
    resources :festivals do
      resources :categories, except: :index
    end
  end

  namespace :curator do
    resources :submissions, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :assessments, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
    end
  end

  root to: 'base_pages#home'

  match '/about',   to: 'base_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'base_pages#contact'
  match '/faq',     to: 'base_pages#faq'
  match '/ping',    to: 'base_pages#ping'
  match '/confirmed',    to: 'base_pages#confirmed'

end
```

Comment: has your `routes.rb` changed?  why is it trying to direct `faq_path` to  `festivals#show`?

Comment: Can you please show us your base_pages controller and festivals controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not being caused by `faq_path` in the spec, but by a missing route called from within `faq.html.erb`, at line 130 (see the spec backtrace).

Comment: Yes; most likely, it's doing something along the lines of `festival_path(@festival)` but @festival is `nil`.